# Unable to aggregate sum of a field after including lookup for another collection where foreign collection field == a given value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 mongo collections - *Transaction* and *Supplier*. I am trying to do an aggregation of the total value of transactions both outside and inside of a given country so I can compare imports vs domestic purchases. When I join the suppliers collection to transactions, my match condition seems to be getting ignored and I am returned the total sum of all transactions. What am I doing wrong?

This is my aggregation, attempting sum of all transactions where location.country == uk

```
let aggs = [
        {
            $match : { type : "out" },
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from:"suppliers",
                let: { country : "$location.country" },
                localField:"supplier",
                foreignField:"_id",
                as:"suppliers",
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: [ '$suppliers.location.country', "United Kingdom" ]
                            }
                        },
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: null,
                total: { $sum : { $divide: ['$price', 100] } }
            },
        }
    ];
```

This is my Transaction schema

```
const TransactionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    item: {type: String, required: true },
    category: {type: String },
    type: { type: String, enum: ['in', 'out'] },
    price: { type: Number, required: true, get: getPrice, set: setPrice },
    description: { type: String },
    supplier: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
        ref: "Supplier"
    },
    customer: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
        ref: "Customer"
    },
    project: { type: String },
    invoice_ref: { type: String },
    payment_method: { type: String },
    parent_transaction: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
        ref: "Transaction"
    },
    date: { type: Date },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now(), immutable: true },
    updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
});
```

This is my suppliers schema

```
const SupplierSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, unique: true
    },
    description: { type: String },
    website: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    location: {
        address: { type: String },
        town: { type: String },
        county: { type: String },
        postcode: { type: String },
        country: { type: String }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input documents and how you expect the output documents from the aggregation to look?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it, not sure if it's there is a cleaner way

```
let aggs = [{
    $facet: {
        domestic: [
            {
                $match : { type : "out" },
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from:"suppliers",
                    localField:"supplier",
                    foreignField:"_id",
                    as:"suppliers",
                }
            },
            { $unwind: "$suppliers" },
            { 
                $match: { 
                    $expr: { $eq: [ "$suppliers.location.country", "United Kingdom" ] } 
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    total: { $sum : { $divide: ['$price', 100] } }
                }
            },
            {
                $project: { total: { $round: ["$total", 2]}  }
            }
        ],
        import: [
            {
                $match : { type : "out" },
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from:"suppliers",
                    localField:"supplier",
                    foreignField:"_id",
                    as:"suppliers",
                }
            },
            { $unwind: "$suppliers" },
            { 
                $match: { 
                    $expr: { $ne: [ "$suppliers.location.country", "United Kingdom" ] } 
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    total: { $sum : { $divide: ['$price', 100] } }
                }
            },
            {
                $project: { total: { $round: ["$total", 2]}  }
            }
        ]
    }
}];
```

That is returning me

```
[{
    "domestic": [
        {
            "_id": null,
            "total": 12298.31
        }
    ],
    "import": [
        {
            "_id": null,
            "total": 8559.1
        }
    ]
}]
```

I noticed the $round function seems to round down to 2 decimal places but it doesn't add a 0